# Creating a Slider paragraph type, how do I manage tabs "on the fly" within that?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, paragraphs

I'm creating a `paragraph type` that represents a Slider. It has a couple of simple fields like "title" and "subtitle". It also has a *variable number of tabs*. The tabs are where the real content is.

Tabs have a title, and a variable number of entity references (to Movies, Characters, etc.). The entities all have an image and link associated with them so a user can click through to the entity's page. I created a `taxonomy` for Tabs and it has a two fields: the title and a list of Entity references.

Essentially there is a hierarchy: Slider contains tabs, tabs contain entities like Movies.

So in the end, the Slider `paragraph type` has a list of `taxonomy` tabs. The problem I have now is that the UI for adding a Slider to a page shows only the Slider's title fields and a list for the tabs *as references* to existing instances of a tab.

That is, a tab needs to be created *beforehand* in a separate tab taxonomy UI before it can be referenced in the Slider's properties.

My question is: **Is there a way to change the form UI to create instances of a Tab taxonomy *on the fly*, while I am creating an instance of the Slider Paragraph type.** I would like to create a complete slider on one form without having to jump back and forth to another page to modify the tabs of the slider.

For clarification, here's a rough mock up of how the tabs are organized in a slider.

[image]

Comment: I think this will probably get closed as recommending a module/opinionated.  I think what you are asking is whether or not there exists functionality to let users create entities while creating a different entity. There is inline_entity_form that would probably allow tat.

Comment: Sounds like this could be done with [inline entity form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) and [`hook_entity_create()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_create/8.2.x) to create tab taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to make the Tabs into a `paragraph type` as well, instead of `taxonomy`. This way the Slider paragraph type would have a reference to a Tab (or group of tabs) and within the UI form for inserting a Slider, it shows the tabs that make up the Slider, along with a form to populate each tab's data points and references in line. This was what I was looking for. A user now does *not* need to go to a separate screen to create a tab first, then attach it to a Slider object.